# pod is not showing in ready state

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to configure php phabricator example from kubernetes but after creating the replication controller. POD is not showing in ready state ever. It shows in below state:

```
NAME                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
phabricator-controller-z0nk3   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          2m
```

Below is the controller yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "phabricator-controller",
    "labels": {
      "name": "phabricator"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "name": "phabricator"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "name": "phabricator"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "phabricator",
            "image": "fgrzadkowski/example-php-phabricator",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http-server",
                "containerPort": 80
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: I figured out that, its happening because the container is getting crashed with exit status 1. But not able to fix it yet.

Comment: My gut tells me it's a resource issue (not enough memory available or the like) but without logs it's really hard if not impossible to help you.

Comment: It was not because of the resource issue. It was because the container was not able to get connected to SQL instance.

Comment: Good for you that you figured the reason—can you please write an answer below and mark it correct so that others are also helped?

Comment: Just for info: in my case it was resource problem - not enough memory available, so I've created a new cluster with more memory and it works fine

Answer (score 5):

This Pod is crash-looping.  You can tell because the number of restarts is greater than zero.

```
kubectl describe pods <pod-name>
```

Should give further details to help debug.  As will

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually tracking issues with `kubectl describe pods <pod-name>` and `kubectl logs <pod-name>` is indeed the default way to track issues, unfortunately in my case it **WASN'T helpful** (at first.) **All logs were nice** or at least were giving **no error or clue** that something goes wrong.
Readiness and Liveness probes were however showing the app is **not passing through**...

So where the devil were hiding?  In my case increasing values for "initialDelaySeconds" and/or "timeoutSeconds" for Readiness and Liveness probes did the thing.

My first assumption was the app has not enough time to reach "Ready status". However app was still not ready and failed in fact... **!!!BUT!!!** extending those values increased deployment attempt time and thus I've been able to reach more logs. And what I got??? **"Database connection failed attempt due to the timeout"**. So no connection to the database, and the app is died in fact. Tricky moment is - timeouts are not appearing quickly and you need to wait a bit more ... at least default values for "initialDelaySeconds" and/or "timeoutSeconds" were unable to give me needed time to see the "database connectivity timeout".

When firewall rule was set to allow app talk to the database, issue has gone!